# Is there a working RTL example of Dynatree

Tags: right-to-left, dynatree

Trying to work with Dynatree to display an RTL tree with dragndrop. tried playing around with the css but it obviously requires more than that. Does anyone have a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket for it:
https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/detail?id=352

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this solution](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-rtl.html), it formats the entire tree and flips the text with: bidi-override.